# Grails "Data source name not found and no default driver specified" error

Tags: grails, jdbc

I am building a Grails application that will connect to a Sybase SQL Anywhere database and I'm getting a very frustrating error that says:

```
URI: /Booklist/user/authenticate
Class: java.sql.SQLException
Message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified`
```

The code I'm using that isn't working is:

`def sql = Sql.newInstance("jdbc:ianywhere://localhost:1234/dbName", "user", "password", "ianywhere.ml.jdbcodbc.jdbc3.IDriver")`

My stack trace is:

```
Line | Method
->>  490 | connect       in ianywhere.ml.jdbcodbc.jdbc3.IDriver
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|    579 | getConnection in java.sql.DriverManager
|    221 | getConnection in     ''
|     16 | getBooks      in Book.groovy
|     11 | authenticate  in UserController.groovy
|    195 | doFilter      in PageFragmentCachingFilter.java
|     63 | doFilter . .  in AbstractFilter.java
|   1110 | runWorker     in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    603 | run . . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run           in java.lang.Thread
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I would strongly recommend that you follow Grails best practices and set up your datasources in the `DataSource.groovy` config file: http://grails.org/doc/2.2.x/guide/conf.html#dataSource instead of rolling JDBC-style code.

Answer (score 1):

If you put the jar file in the lib directory it won't be added to the classpath automatically. Run `grails compile --refresh-dependencies` to get Grails to see it and add it. It's better to register dependencies in `BuildConfig.groovy` though so you let Ivy download the jar once and cache and re-use it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, Mr. Beckwith. So if I add the dependency to my `BuildConfig.groovy`, it'll look something like `runtime 'mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.20'`? How do I find the syntax for the driver I'll be using? I suspect it'll be something like `runtime 'iAnywhere:something something'`, but I don't know how to find that syntax.

Comment: I use http://mvnrepository.com/ and use their search. They don't show Grails syntax, but it's easy to figure out. E.g. see http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.lowagie/itext/4.2.0 - the grails syntax is 'groupId:artifactId:version", so for that it'd be `'com.lowagie:itext:4.2.0'`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Also, congrats on the new Grails book. I look forward to reading it.